# How to skip kafka history data in flink job if certain lag is encountered?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-flink

Sometimes we encounter lag in kafka consumer due to some external issues.

Flink job will always consume kafka history (delayed data) with exactly-once semantics, but here's a scenario:

We will skip delayed data when kafka consumer lag is too much in order to let our downstream service get the latest data in time.
I am thinking to set a window period to do it. What should I code for it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd say your least painful option is to always read all the messages, but do not process (discard them as soon as possible) the ones you want to skip. Just reading and discarding without any further processing is really fast.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You could stop the Flink job and use `kafka-consumer-groups` CLI from Kafka to seek the consumer group forward (assuming Flink is using one, rather than maintaining offsets itself)

When the job restarts, it'll start from the new offset location

Comment: how to make this process automatically instead of manually stoping and restarting

Comment: You can programmatically create a plain KafkaConsumer instance in code and call seek/commit methods externally from the Flink code

Comment: Or, you can try tuning your Flink consumers to run faster by adjusting instance count, poll frequency and buffer sizes rather than skip anything